# Show something in Android Only php

Tags: php, android, html, wordpress

i want to show download button in Android phone only , how can i achieve that ? this is my code

```
<a href="<?php $files = get_children("post_parent=$id&post_type=attachment&post_mime_type=image");if($files){
    $keys = array_keys($files);
    $num=$keys[0];
    $thumb=wp_get_attachment_url($num);
    print "$thumb";}?>">Download</a>
```

i want something like this

if android 
// show this code

else this

Answer (score 0):

You would need to evaluate the value of $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] and display the button based on that. Example:

```
if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Android') !== FALSE) {
  // Display the button
}
```

Check out http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.useful.php which has some more information.

Comment: Remove the "> before 'Download' in your code. i.e. the last line should be: `print "$thumb";}?>Download</a>`

Comment: I can't see your code so it's a little difficult to debug. Can you put the full snippet which includes the bit to decide if it's an Android device, please?

Comment: i am using echo 'my code' replacing // Display the button